# How to make .toThrow react to throw

Tags: javascript, jestjs, throw

Jest `.toThrow` do not react to throw Error('some text')

This code produce an exception

```
if (!['diff', 'plain', 'json'].includes(format.toLowerCase())) {
    throw Error('Wrong format');
  }
```

I'm trying to process it in tests with

```
test('tree, yml, plan, Exception_', () => {
  const fileName1 = '__tests__/__fixtures__/before.json';
  const fileName2 = '__tests__/__fixtures__/after.jso';
  expect(genDiff(fileName1, fileName2)).toThrow();
});
```

But this test is failed

It is strange, because this is processed correctly:

```
test('t', () => {
  expect(() => {
    throw Error();
  }).toThrow();
});
```

How to fix this problem?

Here is the function

```
const genDiff = (fileName1, fileName2, format = 'diff') => {
  const wrongFiles = checkForWrongFiles([fileName1, fileName2]);
  if (wrongFiles.length !== 0) {
    const errorMessage = `Could not find this files:\n ${wrongFiles.join('\n')}`;
    throw errorMessage;
  }
  if (!['diff', 'plain', 'json'].includes(format.toLowerCase())) {
    throw Error('Wrong format');
  }
  ...
  return result;
};
```

Comment: Where is your `genDiff` function?

Comment: Hi, please add the content of the files and how us the entire `genDiff`. We can't guess the content of this function and the context of `format`.

Comment: genDiff - main function, in index.js

Comment: @АндрейДенисов add this function to the question.

Comment: Omri, content of the format and file completely out of question, because exception thrown before any processing. I could put this if on first string in function genDiff, I will see the exception in jest with my eyes, but the test is failed.

Comment: ok. here is the function in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap the call to the function that throws, otherwise the error [is not catched by the assertions](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tothrowerror) (see the note at the bottom). Note that I've wrapped the call to `genDiff` inside a function.

```
test('tree, yml, plan, Exception_', () => {
  const fileName1 = '__tests__/__fixtures__/before.json';
  const fileName2 = '__tests__/__fixtures__/after.jso';
  expect(() => genDiff(fileName1, fileName2)).toThrow();
});
```